# How to scan a folder for new files (CREATE, MODIFY) using beans, annotation and SpringIntegration?

Tags: java, spring, csv, file, annotations

I need to scan the folder for new/changed files. How to do this not on java alone, but on **spring integration** using **@configuration** and different **annotations**?

Comment: You could watch the folder?

Comment: Your current question is unclear and needs to be more precise.

Comment: I have a folder on the local machine (resources folder). I need to scan a folder and report new and modified files. How to do this not in a xml configuration file, but in a java class using spring integration annotations?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.